# Aligning to the center of the page

Tags: html, css

Right now, the below HTML is aligned to the left of the page. Can we align to the center of the page

```
<span class="center"> <u>Weekly : 392K</u> </span>, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="center"> Monthly : 408K </span>, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="center"> Yearly : 605.6K </span>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS?

Comment: No. I am not aware of CSS. So wanted help :)

Comment: If you don't know CSS what is the "center" class used for, javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Option a: use a `display: flex;` while `justify-content: center;` on your CSS `class` center. This would be one way to do it.

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="center"> <u>Weekly : 392K</u> </span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="center"> Monthly : 408K </span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="center"> Yearly : 605.6K </span>
```

Option b: The way I would do it is this way. Instead of putting a `class` on all of your **spans** individually, why not just contain them in a div and use one class? Just define the `width to 100%`, then you all you have to say is `text-align: center;`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span><u>Weekly : 392K</u></span>
  <span>Monthly : 408K</span>
  <span>Yearly : 605.6K</span>
</div>
```

Also - you don't have to use commas to separate your spans. If you wan't them to break and be on their own line you can use `<br>` which breaks the line after each span.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because span elements have a `display: inline` property on them, use a p tag or apply `display: block` to it.